# How to save pandas pivot table to excel pivot table?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

How can I save a pandas pivot table as a excel pivot table? I want to group them by Category 1, Category 2, Item ID and save as an excel pivot table.

```
#Creation of dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({"Category 1": ["Shirt", "Shirt", "Shirt", "Shirt", "Pants",
                         "Pants", "Pants", "Pants", "Pants"],
                   "Category 2": ["Men", "Men", "Women", "Kids",
                         "Men", "Men", "Women", "Women", "Kids"],
                   "Item ID": ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
                   "Price": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "Quantity": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})

df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Category 1","Category 2","Item ID"],values=["Price","Quantity"],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

```
#df:
                                    Price   Quantity
Category 1  Category 2  Item ID     
Pants       Kids        9           7       9
            Men         5           3       6
                        6           4       6
            Women       7           5       8
                        8           6       9
Shirt       Kids        4           3       5
            Men         1           1       2
                        2           2       4
            Women       3           2       5
```

```
#Saving pivot table to excel

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pivot_table.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='dataframe')
writer.save()
```

Excel Output File:

[image: Excel File]

Desired Outcome:

[image: Desired Outcome]

Comment: I am also running into this issue. I've yet to find anything addressing this.